# xterm display with mininet

Tags: networking, x11, mininet, mobaxterm

I am running Mininet as VM and my host machine is Windows 10. I have been successfully able to setup X1 forwarding. The ssh client i am using to login into Mininet VM from host is Mobaxterm.

When i start the mininet topology using `sudo mn`, then `xterm h1` open a display window. All fine.
But the same is not working when I launch mininet custom topology by running python programs.

```
mininet@mininet-vm:~/SocketProgrammingMininet/mininetTopologies$ sudo python vlan_ex1.py
mininet> nodes
available nodes are:
h1 h2 h3 h4 r s5
mininet> xterm h1    << No h1 host's display.

mininet@mininet-vm:~/SocketProgrammingMininet/mininetTopologies$ sudo mn
mininet> nodes
available nodes are:
c0 h1 h2 s1
mininet> xterm h1        << Window for H1 host opens up.
```

Where is the problem here ? Do I need to do some settings in python program or the way i run it ?

Comment: Can you share your vlan_ex1.py code, it is difficult to analyze the problem without it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication in Mininet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67319171/x11-connection-rejected-because-of-wrong-authentication-in-mininet)

Answer (score 0):

I ran a script-generated topology in the same setup (Win10 + mininet VM + scripted topology) and I can confirm that no xterm opens up for me either. I made sure my console was correctly using X-server (wireshark opens beautifully).
Running a script that includes a call like `os.system("xterm")` from each host made it clear as to what the reason may be: my message was `my error was MoTTy X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol`. I also see a `xterm: Xt error: Can't open display %s` which makes me think it can be an xauth thing.

When you look into the documentation of Mininet, though, there's a [section](http://mininet.org/walkthrough/#xterm-display) about debugging through the use of xterm displays, quoting:

> To start an xterm for every host and switch, pass the -x option:
>
> $ sudo mn -x
>
> After a second, the xterms will pop up, with automatically set window
> names.
>
> Alternately, you can bring up additional xterms

This helped me and it should solve your problem... if you still have it after all this time ;)